# Pusher public events not getting read in the Frontend(react)

Tags: reactjs, laravel, websocket, pusher, pusher-js

I'm trying to make custom channel names using the pusher-php in my Laravel backend micro-service and I'm trying to read the events triggered on these channels on my React frontend.

This is how my event file looks like `NewMessage.php`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Chat;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    public $player_id;

    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        logger('NewMessage Event Triggered!');
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['my-channel'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'NewMessage';
    }
}
```

And I'm reading this event on the frontend with this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let channel = client.subscribe(['my-channel']);
    channel.bind("pusher:subscription_succeeded", () => {
      console.log("pusher:subscription_succeeded. Public channel = ", channel);
    })
    channel.bind('NewMessage', (e) => {
      console.log('New Event with name: NewMessage triggered. Event data = ', e);
    })
  }, []);
```

This whole setup is working alright as when I'm trying to achieve this using the channel name 'public' it's working fine and the events are getting read in the frontend. I'm facing this issue just when I change the name of the public channel.

Comment: Did you try to run `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan route:clear` commands after changing channel name?

Comment: Just tried clearing the config and route, still nothing

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing? Please give more info.

Comment: The exact issue is that I'm not able to listen to events on my frontend when I change the name of the channel from 'public' to something else.

Comment: For example: public function broadcastOn()
    {return ['public-channel'];}  when I'm changing the channel name to 'public-channel' here. The frontend doesn't read the events, but it's reading them perfectly fine when I'm doing this: public function broadcastOn()
    { return ['public'];}

Answer (score 0):

add this line to the top:

```
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
```

and return Channel in the broadcastOn() method:

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new Channel('new-channel');
}
```

for more info you can look: https://petericebear.github.io/starting-laravel-echo-20170303/

Comment: I tried doing it that way as well, later on I discovered [pusher-docs](https://pusher.com/docs/channels/server_api/overview/). Where they did it by just return ['new-channel'];

Comment: Is it working when you use `Channel`?

Comment: No, it's just working when I'm naming my channel to 'public'. It's not working when I'm trying to use a channel name like: 'new-channel'